# functions on groups within groups R

Tags: r

let's say I have a dataframe `df` with three columns: `revenue` (int), `quarter` (factor with 4 levels), and `product` (factor with 3 levels).

```
df <- data.frame(
     revenue = sample(500:5000, 10, replace=TRUE),
     quarter = sample(c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"), 50, replace = TRUE),
     product = sample(c("book", "movie", "tv"), 50, replace = TRUE))
```

It would be very easy to use `tapply` to group by either quarter or product and perform a variety of functions on revenue, like this:

```
quarterly_revenue <- tapply(df$revenue, df$quarter, sum)
```

which gives me the sum of revenue per quarter.

However, this is my question: what if I want it more granular, ie: the sum of each product's revenue per quarter? I've tried the `split` function to create a list of dataframes and use various `plyr` solutions, but none give me the output I'm looking for. I know I could subset based on each factor, but that seems inefficient, particularly when the actual set I'm working with has many more factor levels.

any ideas? thanks for the help!

Comment: `aggregate(df$revenue, by= list(df$quarter, df$product),  sum )`

Answer (score 0):

We place the grouping columns in a `list` and get the `sum`

```
tapply(df$revenue, list(df$quarter, df$product),  sum)
```

---

It would be much easier with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(revenue~., df, sum)
```

or `dplyr` or `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(quarter, product) %>%
    summarise(Sum = sum(revenue))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table` with a `by` parameter:

```
library( data.table )
setDT( df )[ , quarterly_revenue := sum( revenue ), 
               by = .( quarter, product ) ]
```

Or, to summarise (instead of just adding a column):

```
library( data.table )
library( magrittr )

setDT( df )[ , sum( revenue ), 
               by = .( quarter, product ) ] %>%
    setnames( c( "quarter", "product", "quarterly_revenue" ) )
```